# How to connect AWS Lambda to Amazon Keyspaces (AWS Cassandra)?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

Looking for a sample program to connect to Amazon Keyspaces (AWS Managed Cassandra) using AWS Lambda, however could not find any sample programs for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, but there seems to be a python example that shows how to do it: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-keyspaces-lambda-python. Basically create IAM users and use those credentials in the lambda.